# TypeScript looking for metro-config in new amplify CDK stack

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify, aws-cdk

I have created a new CDK stack using:

```
amplify add custom
```

When I try to build it, I get the following error:

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'metro-config'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'metro-config'
```

There is no reference anywhere in cdk-stack.ts to `metro-config`. Everything is per default.

I have `metro-config` elsewhere in my repo, but in a different package (Yarn workspace).

I have two workspaces:

- web (Next.js, amplify lives here)
- mobile (React Native, contains metro-config)

Running `tsc` from `web/amplify/backend/custom/mycdk/` also gives the error above.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "build"
  }
}
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "custom-resource",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper": "^3.0.0",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "~2.68.0",
    "constructs": "^10.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

I tried `yarn add @types/metro-config`, as well as `yarn add metro-config`, and nothing changes. Made various changes to `tsconfig.json` and nothing worked, so restored it to default.

I am not using project references. The `tsconfig.json` file is the one generated by Amplify.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps someone: I had this issue and it was because I had both in my project's dependencies "@react-native/metro-config" and "@types/metro-config". Types lib is not needed because metro-config already brings it's own definitions. I removed "@types/metro-config" and the error went away.